# Action.balances payload in reducer not updating physical balances

Tags: reactjs, redux, reducers

In a reducer

The incoming action.payload.balances shows the correct information, however it doesn't update the physical balances piece of state

I'd also like to note that when I'm trying to send a transaction it will call getBalances again & know that I have less than what the UI displays, which is confusing as to why the information isn't updating directly to the balances variable

```
  // Sequence of events (all of these are in different files of course)    

  // Action Call
  export const getBalances = exchange => 
  action(actionTypes.GET_BALANCES.REQUEST, { exchange })

  // Request
  case GET_BALANCES.REQUEST:
    return { ...state, status: 'loading' }

  // Saga 
  export function* getBalances(action) {
    getBalanceCount++
    const state: storeType = yield select()
    yield fork(async, action, API.getBalances, {
      exchange: state.exchanges.selectedExchange._id,
      userId: state.auth.userId,
    })
    if (getBalanceCount > 1) {
      getBalanceCount--
      return
    }
    yield delay(10000)
    if (state.auth.token && state.auth.status === 'success')
      yield put({ type: action.type, payload: {} })
  }

  // API Call
  export const getBalances = ({ userId, exchange }) =>
  API.request(`/wallets/${userId}/${exchange}`, 'GET')

  // Sets balances to the payload.balances
  case GET_BALANCES.SUCCESS:
    return {
      ...state,
      balances: action.payload.balances,
      status: 'success',
    }
```

Entire reducer file

```
    import { mergeDeepRight } from 'ramda'
    import {
      GET_BALANCES,
      GET_EXCHANGES,
      SELECT_EXCHANGE,
      GET_SYMBOL_PRICE_TICKER,
      GET_DAY_CHANGE_TICKER,
      GET_FRIEND_EXCHANGES,
      ADD_EXCHANGE,
    } from '../action-types/exchanges.action-types'
    import { LOG_OUT, VALIDATE_TOKEN } from '../action-types/login.action-types'
    import { ExchangeService } from '../constants/types'

    // Exchanges Reducer

    export type exchangeState = {
      status: string
      _id: string
      label: string
      displayName: string
      dayChangeTicker: any
      symbolPriceTicker: any
      balances: any,
    }

    export type exchangesState = {
      status: string
      selectedExchange: exchangeState
      addExchange: {
        status: string,
      }
      exchanges: Array<ExchangeService>
      friendExchanges: Array<ExchangeService>,
    }

    const initialExchangeState: exchangeState = {
      status: 'pending',
      _id: '',
      label: '',
      displayName: null,
      dayChangeTicker: {},
      symbolPriceTicker: {},
      balances: {},
    }

    const initialState: exchangesState = {
      status: 'pending',
      selectedExchange: {
        status: 'pending',
        _id: '',
        label: '',
        displayName: null,
        dayChangeTicker: {},
        symbolPriceTicker: {},
        balances: {},
      },
      addExchange: {
        status: 'pending',
      },
      exchanges: [],
      friendExchanges: [],
    }

    export default (state = initialState, action) => {
      switch (action.type) {
        case SELECT_EXCHANGE:
        case GET_SYMBOL_PRICE_TICKER.SUCCESS:
        case GET_DAY_CHANGE_TICKER.SUCCESS:
        case GET_BALANCES.REQUEST:
        case GET_BALANCES.SUCCESS:
        case GET_BALANCES.FAILURE:
          return { ...state, selectedExchange: selectedExchangeReducer(state.selectedExchange, action) }

        case GET_EXCHANGES.REQUEST:
        case GET_FRIEND_EXCHANGES.REQUEST:
          return { ...state, status: 'loading' }

        case GET_EXCHANGES.SUCCESS:
          if (action.payload.exchanges.length > 0) {
            return mergeDeepRight(state, {
              exchanges: action.payload.exchanges,
              selectedExchange: { ...action.payload.exchanges[0] },
              status: 'success',
            })
          }
          return { ...state, status: 'success' }

        case GET_FRIEND_EXCHANGES.SUCCESS:
          return { ...state, friendExchanges: action.payload.exchanges, status: 'success' }

        case GET_EXCHANGES.FAILURE:
        case GET_FRIEND_EXCHANGES.FAILURE:
          return { ...state, message: action.payload.message, status: 'failure' }

        case LOG_OUT.SUCCESS:
        case VALIDATE_TOKEN.FAILURE:
          return initialState

        case ADD_EXCHANGE.REQUEST:
          return { ...state, addExchange: { status: 'loading' } }

        case ADD_EXCHANGE.SUCCESS:
          return { ...state, addExchange: { status: 'success' } }

        case ADD_EXCHANGE.FAILURE:
          return { ...state, addExchange: { status: 'failure' } }

        default:
          return state
      }
    }

    const selectedExchangeReducer = (state = initialExchangeState, action) => {
      switch (action.type) {
        case SELECT_EXCHANGE:
          if (action.payload.exchange) {
            return { ...state, ...action.payload.exchange }
          }
          return initialExchangeState

        case GET_SYMBOL_PRICE_TICKER.SUCCESS:
          const symbolPriceTicker = action.payload.data.data.reduce((result, ticker) => {
            result[ticker.symbol] = ticker.price
            return result
          }, {})
          return { ...state, symbolPriceTicker }

        case GET_DAY_CHANGE_TICKER.SUCCESS:
          const dayChangeTicker = action.payload.data.data.reduce((result, ticker) => {
            result[ticker.symbol] = ticker.priceChangePercent
            return result
          }, {})
          return { ...state, dayChangeTicker }

        // Get selected exchange's balances
        case GET_BALANCES.REQUEST:
          return { ...state, status: 'loading' }

        case GET_BALANCES.SUCCESS:
          debugger
          return {
            ...state,
            balances: action.payload.balances,
            status: 'success',
          }

        case GET_BALANCES.FAILURE:
          return { ...state, balances: [], message: action.payload.message, status: 'failure' }

        default:
          return state
      }
    }
```

action.balances.payload: https://i.stack.imgur.com/rsawC.jpg

state.balances: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Drmj3.jpg

I'd expect the payload to update the balances, however it simply isn't doing that

Is everything formatted in a manner that would do this correctly?  Or is likely a JSON formatting issue?

Comment: Could you please show us your entire reducer file, your actions file and how you're calling the action please?

Comment: @Dan updated, appreciate the look!